# develop a chatbot to ask questions with API.ai

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I’m developing a chatbot that not only will answer some FAQs but also capable of asking questions in some sort like a quiz. The problem is, from what I’ve already seen, bot frameworks impose some order (user’s response will serve as an intent for the next question and so on) 
I’m asking is there is a certain way to make the generation of questions a little bit random, coz I don’t want the user to predict every time the question that follows 
PS: I’m currently working with API.ai but I’m open to any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function called "askrandomquestion" and ask questions from there.
Call "askrandomquestion" from your node js file in server(I used fire base).

```
exports.appname = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new App({ request, response });
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  // Greet the user and direct them to next turn
  function unhandledDeepLinks (app) {
      app.ask(`Welcome to Google car assistant `,
        NO_INPUTS);
  }

  // Say a fact
  function askrandomquestion (app) {
var randomnumber = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
switch(randomnumber)
{
//do your logic here
}


};
```

Comment: So i guess the questions will be stored in a data base and won't be treated like intent/action ? 
i would be grateful if you can give me any examples for this function.

Comment: Did you enabled webhook for your api.ai project ?

Comment: Please see the edited answer.You can modify your js file like that